# Get joined string from list of lists of strings in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of lists and a separator string like this:

```
lists = [
    ['a', 'b'],
    [1, 2],
    ['i', 'ii'],
]
separator = '-'
```

As result I want to have a list of strings combined with separator string from the strings in the sub lists:

```
result = [
    'a-1-i', 
    'a-1-ii', 
    'a-2-i', 
    'a-2-ii',
    'b-1-i', 
    'b-1-ii', 
    'b-2-i', 
    'b-2-ii',
]
```

Order in result is irrelevant.

How can I do this?

Comment: At the moment I'm not sure how to get this working in a nice pythonic way and it is not homework ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
from itertools import product
result = [separator.join(map(str,x)) for x in product(*lists)]
```

`itertools.product` returns an iterator that produces the cartesian product of the provided iterables. We need to `map` `str` over the resultant tuples, since some of the values are ints. Finally, we can join the stringified tuples and throw the whole thing inside a list comprehension (or generator expression if dealing with a large dataset, and you just need it for iteration).

Comment: +1 Great answer man - I want to print that and put it on my fridge.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> result = list(product(*lists))
>>> result = [separator.join(map(str, r)) for r in result]
>>> result
['a-1-i', 'a-1-ii', 'a-2-i', 'a-2-ii', 'b-1-i', 'b-1-ii', 'b-2-i', 'b-2-ii']
```

---

As @jpm pointed out, you don't really need to cast `list` to the `product` generator. I had these to see the results in my console, but they are not really needed here.

Comment: You don't need to force the product into a `list` constructor. `map` works just fine on an iterator. Also, you don't need to force the tuples in that iterator into lists. `map` and `join` work just fine on tuples.

Comment: @jpm yes I was still editing that. Initially I had these while trying in my console to see the results, should have removed them later :)

Comment: Another point on forcing the iterator into an intermediate list: if the cartesian product gets large (an entirely possible scenario, despite what this example shows), we probably want to delay putting it all in memory as long as possible. Depending on the application, we may even wish to use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension.

Comment: @jpm aboslutely, I had it to see the results in the console. Should have removed them when posted here :) Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with builtins:

```
>>> map(separator.join, reduce(lambda c,n: [a+[str(b)] for b in n for a in c], lists, [[]]))
['a-1-i', 'b-1-i', 'a-2-i', 'b-2-i', 'a-1-ii', 'b-1-ii', 'a-2-ii', 'b-2-ii']
```

Comment: Nice use of the functional techniques. If you switch the `for` clauses of the comprehension around, you can even match the output requested by the OP.

Comment: As a point of interest, this solution is very slightly slower than mine (not quite 2 seconds over 2,000,000 reps, via timeit). Hardly enough to worry about in almost any application, but I found it interesting.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think too hard about the order of the for terms, but the OP said he didn't care about the order.

Comment: Hence why you still got my +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

```
["%s%c%s%c%s" % (a, separator, b, separator, c) for a in lists[0] for b in lists[1] for c in lists[2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`````````````````````````````
from _ast import List
from itertools import product
import itertools


list1 = [
    ['1', '2', '3'], 
    ['4', '5', '6'], 
    ['7', '8', '9']
]
result = list(map(''.join, product(*list1)))
for s in result:
    print(repr(s))
    
print('............')   
    
for s in map(''.join, product(*list1)):
    print(repr(s))  

print('............')
res = [*map(''.join,product(*list1))]
print(res)
print('............')


ra = list(map(''.join, product(*list1)))
print(ra)

print('............')
for element in itertools.product(*list1):
    print(element)

#If there is a separator 
separator = '-'

#Then,

res2 = [ separator.join(map(str,r))  for r in product(*list1) ]
print(res2)
``````````````````````````

The Output :

```````````````````

['147', '148', '149', '157', '158', '159', '167', '168', '169', '247', '248', '249', '257', '258', '259', '267', '268', '269', '347', '348', '349', '357', '358', '359', '367', '368', '369']
............
['147', '148', '149', '157', '158', '159', '167', '168', '169', '247', '248', '249', '257', '258', '259', '267', '268', '269', '347', '348', '349', '357', '358', '359', '367', '368', '369']
............
('1', '4', '7')
('1', '4', '8')
('1', '4', '9')
('1', '5', '7')
('1', '5', '8')
('1', '5', '9')
('1', '6', '7')
('1', '6', '8')
('1', '6', '9')
('2', '4', '7')
('2', '4', '8')
('2', '4', '9')
('2', '5', '7')
('2', '5', '8')
('2', '5', '9')
('2', '6', '7')
('2', '6', '8')
('2', '6', '9')
('3', '4', '7')
('3', '4', '8')
('3', '4', '9')
('3', '5', '7')
('3', '5', '8')
('3', '5', '9')
('3', '6', '7')
('3', '6', '8')
('3', '6', '9')
['1-4-7', '1-4-8', '1-4-9', '1-5-7', '1-5-8', '1-5-9', '1-6-7', '1-6-8', '1-6-9', '2-4-7', '2-4-8', '2-4-9', '2-5-7', '2-5-8', '2-5-9', '2-6-7', '2-6-8', '2-6-9', '3-4-7', '3-4-8', '3-4-9', '3-5-7', '3-5-8', '3-5-9', '3-6-7', '3-6-8', '3-6-9']
````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````